# golang CLI running gcloud command gets stuck running command

Tags: go

I am creating a Go CLI that will run a gcloud command (specifically in this instance the port forwarding command, which if you go into a Kubernetes cluster -> Services & Ingress.
the command looks like this:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials <k8_name> --zone <zone> --project <project> \
 && kubectl port-forward --namespace <ns> $(kubectl get pod --namespace <ns> --selector="app=<app_name>" --output jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}') <remote_port>:<local_port>
```

here is the code responsible for running this command

```golang
for scanner.Scan() {
    answer := scanner.Text()
    if answer != "y" {
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    c := fmt.Sprintf(`gcloud container clusters get-credentials <k8_cluster> --zone <zone> --project <project> && \
    kubectl port-forward --namespace <ns> $(kubectl get pod --namespace <ns> --selector="app=%s" --output jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}') %d:%d`, app, localPort, remotePort)
    cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", c)

    stderr, err := cmd.StderrPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if err = cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer cmd.Wait()
    go io.Copy(os.Stdout, stderr)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("err: ", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

what I see in the terminal is the following:

```
is the information above correct? (y/n): y
Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
kubeconfig entry generated for <k8_cluster>.
```

and it freezes there.

what I should see is:

```
Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
kubeconfig entry generated for <k8_cluster>.
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8080 -> 61727
Forwarding from [::1]:8080 -> 61727
```